# git show old version of file in editor

Tags: git

I figured out I can show old versions of a file using 'git log filename' to show the commits, and then use 'git show commit-id:filename' for the old version. But it just puts it in less.

I would like to be able to view this in emacs, so I can navigate as I'm used to and so that there is syntax highlighting. I found out I can't set the git core.pager to emacs since emacs cannot read from stdin.

Does anyone know how I could do this? Or do you have another good way of checking old versions of files?

Comment: I *do* have a better way of checking old revisions: with vim :p. A simple `git show commit-id:filename | vim -` and you're done!

Comment: You can also try `most` as pager, it has color support.

Comment: Better answers available at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420282/using-emacs-and-magit-to-visit-a-file-in-given-commit-branch-etc - in particular, `C-x v ~` is great for switching branches too.

Comment: Also if your intent is debugging and tracing a bug by peeking past commits, you can use `git bisect`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Just use `>` and put it into a file that you can open in emacs.

```
git show commit-id:filename > oldfile
```

Then open the file in emacs.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using `bash`, you can use Process Substitution.

```
gvim <(git show commit-id:filename)
```

Comment: When emacs opens it says 'symbolic link to nonexistent file' in the minibuffer and an empty buffer is shown

Comment: I didn't test `emacs <(git show commit-id:filename)`, I am a vim user.... And this command doesn't work with emacs: when emacs opens the temporary file created by the `<(   )` command, the file doesn't exist anymore...

Answer (score 7):

Using the following Vim command, one can view a previous version of a file without having to cleanup anything afterward.

```
 git show commit-id:filename | vim - -n
```

**Explanation**: 
The dash argument of the vim command makes vim load whatever comes in from standard input. The -n option suppresses the creation of swap files.

Comment: This has the downside that you don't get syntax-coloring due to the missing file extension.

Answer (score 3):

Emacs package git-timemachine lets you step back and forth through git revisions of a file:

https://github.com/pidu/git-timemachine